# How to customisly arrange Position absolute div tags

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Here I'm Trying to display `div#content_1 , div#content_2 and div#content_3`  when clicking on corresponding item.I would like to show the last clicked item on top.Here if you click  item3 once then you are not able to view item1 and item2 forever and if you click the item2 once you cannot see the item1 forever.please help me to fix this ,thanks in advance.(consider there we have large no of items )

```js
function getElement(e) {
   var elem = document.getElementById(e);
   return elem;
}

getElement("item_1").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_1").style.display = "block";});
    
getElement("item_2").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_2").style.display = "block";});
    
getElement("item_3").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_3").style.display = "block";});
```

```css
ul,li{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
 }
 div#menu{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
 }
 div#menu>ul li{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  
 #content{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  position :relative;
 }
 
 .abs{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:none;
 }
 
 #content_1{
  background-color:red;
 }
 #content_2{
  background-color:green;
 }
 #content_3{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li id="item_1">menu item1</li>
    <li id="item_2">menu item2</li>
    <li id="item_3">menu item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_1" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_2" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_3" class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope bro ...if you click the 3rd once we are not able to view the item1,item2

Comment: np... i'm edited question ...

Comment: can you use jquery or only js ? i ask because you didn't tag any of them in the question

Comment: @MihaiT both of them will do the job bro

Comment: with jQuery i can make a solution where you don't have to make a click event for every item. Just one that works for all

Comment: @MihaiT add that code bro...that will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you. if you don't want to hide div then just play with z-index.

```js
function getElement(e) {
   var elem = document.getElementById(e);
   return elem;
}

function zIndexZero() {
document.querySelectorAll('.abs').forEach(function(item) {
  item.style.zIndex = 0;
});
}

getElement("item_1").addEventListener("click",function(){

    zIndexZero();
    getElement("content_1").style.display = "block";
    getElement("content_1").style.zIndex = 99;
    });
    
getElement("item_2").addEventListener("click",function(){
    zIndexZero();
    getElement("content_2").style.display = "block";
    getElement("content_2").style.zIndex = 99;
    
    });
    
getElement("item_3").addEventListener("click",function(){
    zIndexZero();
    getElement("content_3").style.display = "block";
    getElement("content_3").style.zIndex = 99;
    });
```

```css
ul,li{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
 }
 div#menu{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
 }
 div#menu>ul li{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  
 #content{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  position :relative;
 }
 
 .abs{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:none;
 }
 
 #content_1{
  background-color:red;
 }
 #content_2{
  background-color:green;
 }
 #content_3{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li id="item_1">menu item1</li>
    <li id="item_2">menu item2</li>
    <li id="item_3">menu item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_1" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_2" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_3" class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the other elements and hide them in your js code:

```js
function getElement(e) {
   var elem = document.getElementById(e);
   return elem;
}

getElement("item_1").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_1").style.display = "block";
    getElement("content_2").style.display = "none";
    getElement("content_3").style.display = "none";    
    });
    
getElement("item_2").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_1").style.display = "none";
    getElement("content_2").style.display = "block";
    getElement("content_3").style.display = "none";   
    });
    
getElement("item_3").addEventListener("click",function(){
    getElement("content_1").style.display = "none";
    getElement("content_2").style.display = "none";
    getElement("content_3").style.display = "block";   
    });
```

```css
ul,li{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
 }
 div#menu{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
 }
 div#menu>ul li{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  
 #content{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  position :relative;
 }
 
 .abs{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:none;
 }
 
 #content_1{
  background-color:red;
 }
 #content_2{
  background-color:green;
 }
 #content_3{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li id="item_1">menu item1</li>
    <li id="item_2">menu item2</li>
    <li id="item_3">menu item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_1" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_2" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_3" class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry bro that is not possible because of 2 reasons.1).actually this divs are like windows even if you close one you need to see the bottom one ,2).consider there are large no of items this code will become large (exponentially).

Comment: @DreamHunter This answer solves the question as asked. If your real question is substantially different, why not ask the real question instead?

Comment: @MrLister i don't think so bro i have been  added there are large no of items on my question everybody understand the situation ,consider there are 10 items and calculate the no of lines when using this code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want

```js
function getElement(e) {
   var elem = document.getElementById(e);
   return elem;
}

$("[id^=item_]").on('click', function () {
        $("[id^=content_]").css("display", "block");
        var id = $(this).prop('id');
        var dataArray = id.split('_');
        var numToCLick = parseInt(dataArray[1]);

        for(var i = 1; i < numToCLick; i++){
          getElement("content_"+i).style.display = "none";
        }
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
 }
 div#menu{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
 }
 div#menu>ul li{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  
 #content{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:200px;
  position :relative;
 }
 
 .abs{
  //position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  float:left;
  display: none;
  
 }
 
 #content_1{
  background-color:red;
 }
 #content_2{
  background-color:green;
 }
 #content_3{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li id="item_1">menu item1</li>
    <li id="item_2">menu item2</li>
    <li id="item_3">menu item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_1" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_2" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_3" class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: oh sorry...i would like to have all the the content areas on one above another

Comment: i know but this is only to show you div are which greater then you clicked are visible not hide if want do stuff something else you can expand the code

Comment: also this is dynamic not need to add  addEventListener for every single item may in dynamic site you don't know how much items you have in list

Answer (score 0):

This is only jq version. You can select the `abs` depending on the id of the `li` item

```js
let item = $("ul li"),
  content = $(".abs")

item.on("click", function() {
  let itemId = $(this).attr("id"),
    idNr = itemId.split('_').pop();
    
  content.removeClass("show")
  $("#content_" + idNr).addClass("show")

})
```

```css
ul,
li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

div#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

div#menu>ul li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: none;
}

#content_1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#content_2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#content_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.abs.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=menu>
  <ul>
    <li id="item_1">menu item1</li>
    <li id="item_2">menu item2</li>
    <li id="item_3">menu item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_1" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_2" class="abs"></div>
  <div id="content_3" class="abs"></div>
</div>
```